# How to calculate next birthday from current date using Jodatime

Tags: datetime, jodatime, date-arithmetic

How to calculate next birthday from current date using Jodatime.

for example current date is May 31, 2016

Birth date is Feb 26, 1991 and July 23, 1991

output looks like below.

```
Birthday        Next Birthday
Feb 26, 1991    Feb 26, 2017
July 23, 1991   July 26, 2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    String d1 = "Feb 26, 1991";
    String d2 = "July 23, 1991";

    DateTimeFormatter f = 
      DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(nextBirthDay(f.parseLocalDate(d1))); // 2017-02-26
    System.out.println(nextBirthDay(f.parseLocalDate(d2))); // 2016-07-23
}

private static LocalDate nextBirthDay(LocalDate date) {

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    int year = today.getYear();

    int month = date.getMonthOfYear();
    int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();

    if (
        today.getMonthOfYear() > month
        || (today.getMonthOfYear() == month && today.getDayOfMonth() > dayOfMonth)
    ) {
        year++;
    }

    return new LocalDate(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}
```